# LabVIEW digital display move with slider

Tags: labview

I want to make a display using vertical pointer slide, is there a way to make the digital display to move with the pointer?

[image]

As seen in the picture, A will slide up and down when the value changes, I want B to move with A when A slides.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.  Please expand upon what you are trying to accomplish and/or provide a simple example.

Comment: Do you mean chart or a graph?

Comment: @DakotaD, I have edited the question, please take a look. Thanks!

Comment: @user408041, please see the edited question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Screenshot (not snipplet!)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsDKa.jpg)

Actual for LabView versions from 8.6 to 2012. Probably in newer versions that's can be made easier.
And yes, there is lack of checks to a negative ranges of slider values.

[AdvMoving.vi (LV 8.6 - 2012)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-on-dMnHj8dSkRhTVNkenl4NTA)